# What is wrong with my AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have followed this tutorial to create thumbnails of images to another bucket with AWS Lambda: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/walkthrough-s3-events-adminuser-create-test-function-upload-zip-test.html

I have done all the steps earlier in the tutorial but when I run the code below in Lambda test from the link above

```
{  
   "Records":[  
      {  
         "eventVersion":"2.0",
         "eventSource":"aws:s3",
         "awsRegion":"us-east-1",
         "eventTime":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
         "eventName":"ObjectCreated:Put",
         "userIdentity":{  
            "principalId":"AIDAJDPLRKLG7UEXAMPLE"
         },
         "requestParameters":{  
            "sourceIPAddress":"127.0.0.1"
         },
         "responseElements":{  
            "x-amz-request-id":"C3D13FE58DE4C810",
            "x-amz-id-2":"FMyUVURIY8/IgAtTv8xRjskZQpcIZ9KG4V5Wp6S7S/JRWeUWerMUE5JgHvANOjpD"
         },
         "s3":{  
            "s3SchemaVersion":"1.0",
            "configurationId":"testConfigRule",
            "bucket":{  
               "name":"sourcebucket",
               "ownerIdentity":{  
                  "principalId":"A3NL1KOZZKExample"
               },
               "arn":"arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket"
            },
            "object":{  
               "key":"HappyFace.jpg",
               "size":1024,
               "eTag":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
               "versionId":"096fKKXTRTtl3on89fVO.nfljtsv6qko"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I get the error message

> Unable to resize sourcebucket/HappyFace.jpg and upload to
>   sourcebucketresized/resized-HappyFace.jpg due to an error:
>   PermanentRedirect: The bucket you are attempting to access must be
>   addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future
>   requests to this endpoint. END RequestId: 345345...

I have changed the bucket name, eTag and image name. Do I need to change something else? My region are correct. Do I need to edit "principalId"? Where can I find it?

What is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the problem was the bucket region. In the example "us-east-1" is used, but my bucket is on "eu-west-1", so i had to change 2 things:

- `"awsRegion":"eu-west-1",`   in lambda test file
- set region in my nodejs lambda code: `AWS.config.update({"region": "eu-west-1"})`

And of course you still need to set following values in in lambda test file:

- `name: 'your_bucket_name_here',`
- `arn: 'arn:aws:s3:::your_bucket_name_here'`

After this modifications it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is about "endpoint".You must change  "arn":"arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket" to "arn":"arn:aws:s3:::(name_of_your_bucket)". Same to  "name":"sourcebucket" to  "name":"(name_of_your_bucket)".

In order to avoid more problems you must upload a jpg called HappyFace.jpg to your bucket or change in s3 put Test object code.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try use this updated format (Please carefully configure the key, bucket name,arn and awsRegion to your own settings):

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "s3": {
        "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
        "object": {
          "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901",
          "key": "HappyFace.jpg",
          "size": 1024
        },
        "bucket": {
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::myS3bucket",
          "name": "myS3bucket",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
          }
        },
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH",
        "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789"
      },
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      },
      "eventSource": "aws:s3"
    }
  ]
}
```